# Deleting from Local SQL table and in server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-delete, data-synchronization, sql-query-store

I have a simple Stationary database whoes UI is a C# application Stationary. Anyone who installs the application will have a local SQL database and the existing data in stationary database from the server is automatically synchronized. It has a simple ItemList.dbo SQL table as below.

[image: ItemList.dbo]

***Scenario:***
1. When users add information into ItemList.dbo it first gets added in their local SQLExpress database.This is because they work without internet and end of day they synchronize to the server and the data in local database gets added to the server. 
2. In case 2 users use different computers when synchronized information from user1 & user 2 sent to server is available on all machines and server

I need help how to implement deletion.For example, if user 1 deletes 2 rows it gets deleted from local server then when synchronizes their machine the rows missing from the local database gets added back to the server. Because according to initial logic the server adds items that are not present in local machine. How should I implement delete in this situation?

If user 1 or user 2 deletes the information from local database upon synchronize it must delete in server.

Please guide.
Regards,
NewBee

Comment: You say this is a "simple" database, but replication is a far from simple task. What I don't understand is what the internet has to do with anything; surely these PCs are on a local network where the database can be hosted. if they aren't on a local network, how do they get the database each morning, and synchronise at the end of each day in the first place? Storing multiple copies of the same database on each users desktop, and then syncing sounds like far more work than having a single local host.

Comment: Uesrs are at different locations hence we have the synchronization working. They work at different sites and server is centrally located. To synchronize they have to connect to internet.  Recording at different sites goes into same database tables which is needed by each site. If site 1, user 1 has already entered item XYZ site2, can't re-add but can edit, delete.

Comment: When you say "synchronization," what is the exact mechanism you are using? SQL Server Replication? Or some homebrew mechanism?